# Online audio troubles in Firefox

Tags: firefox, mp3, internet-radio

I tried to hear some online radio, but have en error message in Firefox.

> totem-plugin-viewer requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) decoder

Meanwhile Google Chrome plays same radio. How can I make Firefox play online radio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is fixed after installing *Adobe flash plugin* for Mozilla from Ubuntu Software Center

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look for "gstreamer plugins" in the software center.
In the description it will show wich one you need for mp3.

if you don't find anything you probably have to enable Universe and Multiverse sources.
you can do so[image] under edit >> software sources.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it didn't help. I guess there are some problems with Firefox, cause Google Chrome plays this radio.